# how to browse previous twitter tweets

Tags: twitter

I'd like to read all past tweets with a hash starting from previous 30 days. Currently I use browser and keep pressing end key until all the past content is loaded. Is there any tool which makes is easier?

Comment: Interesting question! Note that Super User doesn't deal with web apps; but there is a [webapps.se] site that could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution in Twitter UI - in search engine I set past dates limit (lets say 3 days) and add required hashtag. When I browse this past 3 days I change searching conditions to next 3 days